Argument passed in the step definition is not reading and expect fixtures
pytest 8.3.2, pytest-bdd=7.2.0
This is my feature file:
Feature: Blog
    A site where you can publish your articles.

Scenario: Publishing the article
    Given "test" the application

Below is step definition file. But when I run it, I'm getting issue as  fixture 'phrase' not found. Not sure why it expects the fixtures here. I don't want to have the fixtures for my scenario now.
scenario('../features/test_app.feature', 'Publishing the article')

@given(parsers.parse(" {phrase} the application"))
def test_app(phrase):
    print(phrase)

I expect the argument passed in the function should be passed

When you run pytest (with or without pytest-bdd installed), it executes all functions which start with test. The name of your step definition function is test_app(), so it is being picked up as a normal (non-BDD) pytest test function.
All you need to do is rename the function!
Edit: also, you have an extra space at the start of your parsed sentence--you will need to remove that for the step definition to be matched correctly.

I removed the test from method name, but it does no tests ran as error

Did you also remove the extra space at the start of the parsed step string like I mentioned? If so, please post the specific error message you are getting
